# How to set background-size to "cover", plus a little more in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a container with a fixed height of 850px. I want a background-image that will keep the entire background covered at all levels of zoom. I would use `background-size: cover` however, I need it to be a little bit bigger than `cover` will make it. I want some of the background to be bleed out of the container and be unseen, for the purpose of creating a parallax.

Basically how can I use `background-size: cover`, and increase the size a little bit on top of that?

edit: Forgot to mention I'm also using `background-attachment: fixed`, so if I'm not mistaken, its actually calculated via the size of the browser window(?) and not the 850px tall container. How would I add that extra bleed in this case?

Comment: Did you try with `padding-top`?

Comment: I'd put a container inside the current and make it a "little more" bigger, then put the background on that at `cover` with the other having `overflow:hidden`... at least that's where I'd start.

Comment: @Vucko how do you mean?

Comment: @JeremyMiller That sounds right. Let me give that a shot.

Comment: Yeah, it would have been nice if support for syntax like `calc(cover + 10%)` had been implemented.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply using `background-size: auto 110%;` did the trick.

Comment: However, this does not have the functionality of `cover`. It needs to be able to switch to `background-size 100% auto` when the width of the background becomes smaller than that of the browser.

Comment: Anyone know I should go about implementing the javascript to do such?

Comment: Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 9):

This is an old thread but I found a solution to this so thought I'd share.

Using `background-size: auto 110%;` doesn't really work because you lose the `cover` functionality. For responsive and more dynamic elements, you can end up with undesired blank spaces.

Instead, create a wrapping div with `position:relative; overflow:hidden;`. Then within that create your background div with `position:absolute;` and some additional settings. See below.

```css
.banner-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 340px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.banner {
  position: absolute;
  left: -40px;
  right: -40px;
  top: -40px;
  bottom: -40px;
  width: calc(100% + 40px);
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Lang%27s_short_tail_blue_%28Leptotes_pirithous%29_male_underside.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner-wrapper">
  <div class="banner">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice trick!  More robust than the `auto 110%` answer.  A couple points: I don't think the width is necessary unless there's a cross-browser reason for doing so.  If there is, the width should technically be `calc(100% + 80px)` to account for `-40px` on both sides.

Answer (score 2):

Example hover cover background
https://codepen.io/Guirec/pen/VbxaMq?editors=1100

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="image zoom-in">
    <span>Zoom in</span>
  </div>
  <div class="image zoom-out">
    <span>Zoom out</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.image {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000;
  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/700/400/?random");
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid #000;

  span {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}

.zoom-in,
.zoom-out {
  &::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: inherit;
    background-size: cover;
    transform-origin: center;
    transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
  }
}

.zoom-in {
  &:focus,
  &:hover {
    &::after {
      transform: scale(1.05);
    }
  }
}

.zoom-out {
  &::after {
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }

  &:focus,
  &:hover {
    &::after {
      transform: scale(1);
    }
  }
}

/* Nothing interesting  */
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 2vw;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 4vw;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;

  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}

.image {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 25vw;
  margin: 2vw;

  &:nth-child(2n) {
    background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/700/400/?random=2");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I set the container div to: height:100vh, overflow: hidden; then then the inner one to 110% (or however long you want in your paralax), now you can change the background property and cover will always work